# Change date '01-Sept-20' to '01-Sep-20' using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a huge .csv file with date as one of the column and I'm trying to plot it on a graph but I'm getting this error

> "time data '01-Sept-20' does not match format '%d-%b-%y' (match)"

I'm using this line of code to convert it into datetime format

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%d-%b-%y")
```

I think this error is because 'Sept' should be 'Sep'
What can I do to make Sept to Sep?
I'm using this dataset: [covid19 api](https://api.covid19india.org/csv/latest/state_wise_daily.csv)

Comment: Just replace `Sept` with `Sep` and then run your command. Like this maybe: `df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.replace('Sept', 'Sep')`

Comment: With this line of code `df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace('01-Sept-20', value='01-Sep-20')` I'm able to replace it but there are lots of dates with 'Sept'. how to replace all of them at once? Directly adding `replace('Sept', 'Sep')` does not work.

Comment: Do not replace a specific date. Replace the word `Sept`, like in my first comment.

Comment: Is `Sept` the only abbreviation that strptime can't parse or do you have others in your data?

Comment: Okay so @MayankPorwal first comment solution worked only had to add regex=True in the replace function. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mayank pointed out in the comment you could replace the "Sept" string. And it works.

However, in your dataset is a column named Date_YMD which will give you the date without string replacement.

A complete example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('covid.csv')
df['Date_YMD'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_YMD'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.replace('Sept', 'Sep'), format='%d-%b-%y')
```

I think the main point here is to familiarize yourself with the data before searching for a technical solution.

Comment: Yes I had tried using Date_YMD in the past but it gave me further complexities in my application so I had to stick with the Date column only.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried that replace function only had to add regex=True which I had missed.